# Retrieve value from a hashtable with dynamic key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable

I have a hashtable "Param" which has keys which are created dynamically.
e.g 
key : chkbox_1 Value: 1 
key : chk_box_2 Value : 2 
key : chk_box_3 Value 
and so on.

Now I want to get all the values for keys which are LIKE "chkbox_"
I can't do Param.ContainsKey["chkbox_" + id ] because I don't know the "id" part.

So basically I want to do something like Param.ContainsKey LIKE "chkbox_".

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it non-generic `HashTable` or generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: So why did you put `HashTable` in your question?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking something else. It is infact a non-generic Hashtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through all the pairs:

```
var values = dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith("chkbox_"))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

If you're using a non-generic `HashTable` you'll have to cast:

```
IEnumerable<object> values = dict.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Where(de => ((string)de.Key).StartsWith("chkbox_"))
    .Select(de => de.Value);
```

Comment: @Mithil - I'd recommend using a generic collection if possible, but you can use `Hashtable` if you cast, see update.

Comment: Lee, I am new to LINQ. Can you tell me why are you casting the key as "Checkbox"?

Comment: @Mithil - Sorry, I thought your keys were checkboxes, if they're strings you can just cast to that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Both `HashTable` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` require you to know the key to perform fast *O(1)* lookup for value. If you don't know the key you'll have to iterate over entire collection and check all the keys to find what you're looking for.

You should consider changing your collection to e.g. `SortedList`, which would allow you to find items with `LIKE 'Prefix%'` predicate in *O(log n)* time instead of *O(n)* for standard linear search.